# Cartesian product and Russel's paradox

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The Cartesian product is a function with of arguments which assigns to any two sets the set of tuples consisting of an element of the first set and an element of the second:
$$
(A, B) \mapsto A\times B = \{(a, b):\, a\in A,\, b\in B\}.
$$

A function $f: A\to B$ is a subset of $A\times B$ which left-total and right-unique.

It seems to me that the domain of the cartesian product is $M\times M$ and its range is $M,$ where $M$ is set set of all sets. But that does not exist, by Russel's paradox.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The cartesian product is defined for a pair of existing sets and it is not defined on the "whole universe".

Comment: Cartesian product is not what you call a function (i.e. special set of ordered pairs). It must be looked at as an operation. Comparable with e.g $a\mapsto\wp(a)$. Every set has a powerset, but $\wp$ is not a function.

Comment: Using the axioms of set theory we **prove** that - for any two sets $A$ and $B$ - it exists the set $A \times B$. This amounts to proving that $x \in A \times B \text { iff } x \in \mathcal P(\mathcal P(A \cup B)))$.

Comment: Careful when you say 'the set of all sets does not exist, by Russel's paradox'.  New Foundations has a set of all sets, but it still manages to avoid Russell's paradox.  What Russell's paradox tells us is that a set of all sets cannot exist in any consistent formulation of set theory for which we can apply separation to that set of all sets.

Comment: It is, by the way, perfectly legal to talk about $\_ \times \_$: it is a *function class* on sets: that is, we can come up with a first-order formula $\phi[x,y,z]$ such that $\phi[A,B,C]$ is true if and only if $C=A\times B$.  Such function classes are an important part of the definition of the Axiom of Replacement.